# Mounting a board to a tree without screws

Tags: outdoor, mounting, brackets, tree

I'm looking for suggestions on permanently mounting a board vertically to a tree but without drilling into the tree or harming it.  I was looking for some type of bracket or strap that would withstand multiple years of weather (i.e., not rust or disintegrate after one+ year of weather).

The board will support lighted house numbers and will be about 30" long by 3-4" wide (final width tbd), so I'll secure it in at least two spots, maybe three. The trunk of the tree has a circumference between 60-70" depending on the spot along the trunk.

Comment: So, "permanent" or "more than one year?" - there's not much that fits the former and yet also does not involve damage or potential damage to the tree. There's options that could do more than one year, probably without damage, but they won't be permanent.

Comment: Just an idea but would not an elasticated rubber strap not serve this purpose, it would expand as the tree grows, there robust and weather resistant.

Comment: How will the numbers be lighted?

Comment: @Johnliverpool  Expand this a bit and should make a decent answer for the OP.

Comment: This might be something better suited for [gardening.se].

Comment: See this post https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/37165/14392 or this one https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/53439/14392

Comment: Bugs and birds do far more damage than a couple of thin screws. The tree doesn't care.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Gardening and Landscaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some states that allow you to leave tree stands on public hunting land, they recommend ratchet straps to protect the tree as you are intending.  You will want to check and adjust periodically.  A heavy duty strap will last several years but not forever if it gets direct sunshine.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. I was looking at treehouse solutions earlier but the ones I came across involved boring into the tree/support structure.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using elastic clinch straps. They're robust, weather resistant and non-slip. The elastic would expand as the tree grows and last for many years.

[Trilancer was the first manufacturer that came up on Google](http://www.trilancer.site/info.asp?id=253)

These can be strapped together to any length. They just require the board to have fixings on the back to loop the strap through.

Comment: Those don't look to be particularly weather-resistant.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at something similar but would agree that this brand doesn’t look too weather-resistant. I have been having some trouble finding a metal band that would fit the circumference of the tree — I have to imagine that size band is out there or that I could link a few together.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm looking for suggestions on permanently mounting a board vertically to a tree but without drilling into the tree or harming it."  That thought along with , "I was looking for some type of bracket or strap that would withstand multiple years of weather (i.e., not rust or disintegrate after one+ year of weather."  Makes things about impossible.

I applaud you concern for the well being of the tree.

The tree will grow, trunk expand and move.  It is a living thing.  So attachment by anything will need to be something that can move or withstand movement. Then add the need to be long lasting and do no harm to the tree. This limits your choices to some type of magic ....

```
                                  OR
```

Attach the board to a post in front of the tree.

Comment: Attaching to a post in front of the tree will likely encounter the root system and could potentially cause damage as well. It's a toss up for sure.

Comment: If only I had thought of such an obvious solution before posting my question for something more specific… thank you for your contribution.